# Why I am not able to decompile this contract?

Tags: solidity, etherscan, bytecode, bsc

I wanted to decompile [this](https://bscscan.com/address/0xa01af66c02c5bc9320036cc2e8665a35d7051161#code), contract but for some reason the output saying only:

> No regular functions. That's it.

Here is the full output:

```
#
#  Panoramix v4 Oct 2019 
#  Decompiled source of bsc:0xa01aF66c02c5bc9320036cC2E8665a35D7051161
# 
#  Let's make the world open source 
# 
#
#  I failed with these: 
#  - _fallback()
#  All the rest is below.
#


#
#  No regular functions. That's it.
#
```

I don't understand how that is possible because this contract is used to execute swaps on PancakeSwap so there has to be at least one function... any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can decompile it [here](https://ethervm.io/decompile). Simply paste the bytecode from [here](https://bscscan.com/address/0xa01af66c02c5bc9320036cc2e8665a35d7051161#code). You must remove the leading `0x` before decompiling.